# How to define a resource with JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In JNI, I know that you can define a class using `env->DefineClass`. For example,

```cpp
jclass klass = client->env->DefineClass(nullptr, classLoader, (const jbyte*) classBytes, (jsize) classBytes_size);
```

Similarly, I expected there to be a function that defines a resource at runtime, too. By "resource", I mean files that are packaged inside a jar file, like images or sounds. But, I couldn't find any function that does that. Why is there no `DefineResource` function? If it is possible, how do you do that?

Edit: I figured out how to add a URL, which points to my directory, to the classloader. However, the program still can't find my resource.

Code (jni):

```cpp
// Creates a File object to the folder, then converts to a URL and then passes it to the ClassLoader.
#define checkNull(x) checkNull_(#x, x)

template <class T>
void checkNull_(const std::string &varName, T x) {
    if (!x) throw std::runtime_error(varName + " is null");
}

void JavaUtils::addClassLoaderURL() {
    jobject classLoader = getClassLoader();
    checkNull(classLoader);
    jclass URLClassLoader = app->getClass("java.net.URLClassLoader");
    checkNull(URLClassLoader);
    jclass File = app->getClass("java.io.File");
    checkNull(File);
    jclass URI = app->getClass("java.net.URI");
    checkNull(URI);
    jmethodID fileConstructor = app->env->GetMethodID(File, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    checkNull(fileConstructor);
    jstring classpath = app->env->NewStringUTF("~/classpath");
    checkNull(classpath);
    jobject fileObject = app->env->NewObject(File, fileConstructor, classpath);
    checkNull(fileObject);
    jmethodID toURI = app->env->GetMethodID(File, "toURI", "()Ljava/net/URI;");
    checkNull(toURI);
    jmethodID toURL = app->env->GetMethodID(URI, "toURL", "()Ljava/net/URL;");
    checkNull(toURL);
    jobject URIObject = app->env->CallObjectMethod(fileObject, toURI);
    checkNull(toURL);
    jobject URLObject = app->env->CallObjectMethod(URIObject, toURL);
    checkNull(URLObject);
    jmethodID addURL = app->env->GetMethodID(URLClassLoader, "addURL", "(Ljava/net/URL;)V");
    checkNull(addURL);
    app->env->CallVoidMethod(classLoader, addURL, URLObject);
    if (app->env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE) {
        std::cout << "Exception:" << std::endl;
        jthrowable exception = app->env->ExceptionOccurred();
        app->env->ExceptionClear();

        JavaUtils::getInformation(exception);
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Successfully added path to classloader" << std::endl;
}
```

The contents of the folder:

```
 ~
 - classpath
 - - test
 - - - version.txt
```

Code that fails:

```java
InputStream input = VersionManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/test/version.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input); // null pointer exception (because the resource does not exist)
```

Comment: Why? You should aim to keep your JNI as minimal as possible. It's far easier to do this stuff at the Java level.

Comment: `~/classpath` is not a valid filename. `~` is only understood by Unix shells. And even if it was, `classpath` is not a part of your CLASSPATH unless you have made it so somewhere. You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @user207421 I'm doing this because I don't have access to the program's code or command line arguments. And the whole point of this post is to add this path to the classpath at runtime.

Comment: @user207421 and using the full path name doesn't work either.

Comment: Omg I made a mistake, thanks @user207421! Using the full path name worked!

Answer (score 0):

A "resource" is just an ordinary file on one of the class path entries.
If you run your code with `java -cp ...:$SOME_DIRECTORY` you can drop files in `$SOME_DIRECTORY` and they will be picked up. Of course at that point you might as well use plain file handling methods ..

The reason why JNI *does* has a `DefineClass` is so that you can define new Java classes without writing them to a file first and having a ClassLoader instance pick them up.

Comment: What about doing it at runtime where you can't add -cp?

Comment: Please add all constraints and requirements to your question up front instead of moving the goal posts. Saves time and frustration for everyone. The solution there is to add the path to one of the three classloaders available to any piece of code, or chain a classloader with the wanted path to those classloaders.

Comment: I'm sorry someone downvoted, but can you provide code for java 16 either in java or JNI? That would help a lot.

Comment: Also, does classloader also load resources as well as classes?

Comment: Yes. See `getResourceAsStream` and `findResource` methods.

Comment: "providing code" is highly situational. How is your current code retrieving resources? Which of the three classloaders is it using? How is the JVM started and what influence do you have? Edit your question with all these details.

Comment: Please see my editted post where I provide my approach that does not work.